# Change content language for one page

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, language

I have one page witch has a different language then the rest of the site.

I looked in to many plugins but I can't find a way to chance the content language `<html lang="nl-NL" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` for just one page.

I use Yoast SEO and he uses `<meta property='og:locale' content='nl_NL'/>` and that also needs to be en_us

Answer (score 1):

Likely you will need to do a bit of custom [filtering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) to get this done.

HTML part likely comes from [`language_attributes()`](http://queryposts.com/function/language_attributes/) function and passes through `language_attributes` filter.

WP SEO part comes from `WPSEO_OpenGraph->locale()` and passes through `wpseo_locale` filter.

Comment: how could i filter one page for example using as an example ID 123.

Comment: @RoyvanWensen using `if ( is_page( 123 ) )` inside your filter function for example

Comment: i know how to use is_page()

But i don't know how to use language_attributes() and WPSEO_OpenGraph->locale() :-)

Comment: @RoyvanWensen please see linked [filtering documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter), you don't need to use those functions, you only need to learn a bit how to use _any_ filter in WordPress, which is very important skill for it :)